# What is the difference between "content type" and "custom content type"?

Tags: nodes

Can anyone explain to me the difference between *content type* and *custom content type*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Custom content type* can be used with two different meanings:

- Any node type ([bundle](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/bundles), or entity bundle, in Drupal 8 terminology) created from the user interface (admin/structure/types/add in Drupal 7 and Drupal 8) from users with the right permissions
- Any node type implemented from third-party modules

What is not a custom content type is a content type created from a Drupal core module, or a Drupal core profile. For example, the [*Forum topic*](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/forum/config/optional/node.type.forum.yml) content type is created from the Forum module, while the [*Article*](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/profiles/standard/config/install/node.type.article.yml) content type is created from the Standard profile.

For the rest, there isn't much difference between a custom content type and a content type: Both can be extended with fields.
There could be a difference between a content type created from a module (core module or third-party module) and a content type created through the user interface: the content type fields that aren't created from the user interface made available from the [*Field UI*](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/field-ui) module. For example, the Forum module adds to the *Forum topic* content type a [reference field for a vocabulary the module created](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/forum/config/optional/field.field.node.forum.taxonomy_forums.yml). Similarly, the Standard profile adds [a field to attach an image](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.field.node.article.field_image.yml) to nodes of the *Article* content type.

Answer (score 3):

A content type is a type of node. Node types (aka content types) are generally created through the browser UI. However, they can also be created through code, which people refer generally refer to as a custom content type.

Comment: _Custom content type_ has always meant _content type created by the user_ in my experience. The docs seem to agree: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/nodes-content-types-and-fields/create-a-custom-content-type

Comment: Then again the D8 docs page with a similar title refer to them as those created in YML: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/creating-a-custom-content-type-in-drupal-8. So I think the take away is that _custom_ means whatever you want it to mean, and doesn't have particular significance in Drupal

Comment: Yeah, it's not really an official term. Just whatever a person thinks it is when they refer to it.

Comment: But I thought the custom content type WAS the content created in the UI?? I am hearing "content type" and "custom content type" as synonymous phrases which I why I am getting confused. I thought the custom content type is similar to "custom post types" in WordPress. I know you DONT want to give that kind of control to a user/editor generally which is why I'm thinking allowing a user to make a whole other custom content type might be haphazard down the road. Does anybody have any clarity on my thought process?

Comment: Forget WP that'll confuse things more, you just need to get a handle on basic Drupal terminology... _content type_ is a type of content. _Content_ is a piece of content - an instance of a content type. Anywhere you see the word _Custom_ prepended to _content type_, you can pretty much assume it just means _this one was created by a user, not by a core or contributed module_. Whether that happened through the UI or code is largely irrelevant. Drupal doesn't have an official concept of a _custom_ content type, just content types, the prefix comes from the people who are using it to build things

Comment: I have no idea about wordpress, but you wouldn't give editors permission to create content types, but you would give them permission to create content.